# Laravel 4 controller routes not working due to apache2 configuration

Tags: php, apache, apache2, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up laravel on my local server at home and I can't seem to 
get controller routes working eg:

```
Route::controller('home','home');
```

This code works on a server I have at work and I've read a few forums about the
issue which claim the issue is because apache2 isn't configured to look at the
.htaccess files.

I've been messing around with that for a while but I still can't seem to get anything to work.
I went into /etc/apache2/sites-available and created my own config file called site1 which
looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

I then ran a2dissite default && a2ensite site1 and /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
but nothing happened.

Thanks for your help and let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Turns out apache isn't even reading the .htaccess file. I purposely wrote some nonsense
in it that should have caused an error and it didn't.

Comment: Did you enable mod rewrite and is the .htaccess file present? Are there any errors or access logs?

Comment: modrewrite is enabled in the .htaccess file in /laravel/public

Comment: Any errors or accesslog to see what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that mod_rewrite.c wasn't enabled, 
so I ran a2enmod rewrite and everything started working. I noticed that
the .htaccess file in laravel was dependent on it. Silly me. Thanks for all the
help.

Comment: Just a heads up, `.htaccess` provided by laravel automatically inserts `index.php` in the url. However, I set up a test host with `Apache`'s user directory feature, and that `.htaccess` doesn't work with `https://localhost/~username/something` URLs.

Answer (score 3):

In the .htaccess try replacing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

EDIT:

In that case I think that your virtual host is not set in the httpd.conf.
You can try this out and see whether it works or not:

Put this line in the httpd.conf file

For windows

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourlaravel.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/laravel/public">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
     <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For Linux

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourlaravel.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">
 </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "/var/www"
   <Directory "/var/www">
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And to run it in your local machine

For window open the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts put this line.

```
 yourserverip   yourlaravel.com
```

For linux open the \etc\hosts put this line.

```
 yourserverip   yourlaravel.com
```

Your can refer to this link for further info:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/building-web-applications-from-scratch-with-laravel/

I hope this can be some help.

Comment: That didn't do anything. Apache isn't even reading the .htaccess file

Comment: I have edited the answer please try it out and see whether it works or not.

Comment: Yeah sadly apache still isn't reading the .htaccess file in laravel. I tried putting some gibberish in there and the site didn't crash. Your answer did help me remove the /public from the url though and that's an issue I've been meaning to figure out so thanks for that. I also removed the blocker in apache2.conf that apparently prevents .htaccess from being read so maybe that helped but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error often appears when your `public/.htaccess` is not correct. Try this one :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: my htaccess is the same as that except with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d added

Answer (score -1):

If you are uploading to AWS EC2, use default `/var/www/html` as the root directory:

```
[ec2-user@www html]$ pwd

/var/www/html

[ec2-user@www html]$ ll

-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user   146 Nov 10 06:29 CONTRIBUTING.md 
drwxr-xr-x 12 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Mar  8 16:21 app 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ec2-user ec2-user  2452 Nov 10 06:29 artisan  
drwxr-xr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Mar  5 00:18 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user   717 Nov 10 06:29 composer.json  
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user 58819 Jan 11 22:00 composer.lock 
drwxr-xr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Jan 11 22:24 nbproject  
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user   567 Nov 10 06:29 phpunit.xml  
drwxr-xr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Nov 10 06:29 public    
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user  2051 Nov 10 06:29 readme.md
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user   519 Nov 10 06:29 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 20 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Jan 11 22:00 vendor
```

Keep ec2-user as the owner of all the laravel files. Execute:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 app/storage  

$ sudo php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

**https.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost  
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/" 
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI  
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted  
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/html/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```